# Get build output into TeamCity Build log from Xamarin mdtool via Rake script

Tags: rake, teamcity, xamarin.mac, mdtool

I am building a Xamarin.Mac application with a OS X build agent via Xamarin Studio. The build script is writtenw in Rake and is very simple:

```
task :default => [:build]

task :build do
     `/Applications/Xamarin\\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/mdtool -v build -p:"EyeLoe.Main" -t:Build "EyeLeo.Mac.sln"`
end
```

Whenever TeamCity is running a rakefile withing a RakeRunner build step, I only get the following in the build log:

```
Step 1/1: Run Build (Rake) (3s)
[13:32:26][Step 1/1] Starting: /usr/bin/ruby /Applications/buildAgent/plugins/rake-runner/rb/runner/rakerunner.rb --rakefile /Applications/buildAgent/work/bc2e9e29fc298503/Rakefile
[13:32:26][Step 1/1] in directory: /Applications/buildAgent/work/bc2e9e29fc298503
[13:32:26][Step 1/1] 
[13:32:26][Step 1/1] Invoke default (2s)
[13:32:26][Invoke default] 
[13:32:26][Invoke default] (first_time)
[13:32:26][Invoke default] 
[13:32:26][Invoke default] Execute build (2s)
[13:32:28][Execute build] 
[13:32:28][Invoke default] 
[13:32:28][Invoke default] Execute default
[13:32:28][Invoke default] 
[13:32:28][Step 1/1] Process exited with code 0
```

I don't know if it really builds since no bin/obj directories are created in the build folder. But the main thing I need is to see a build log from Xamarin Studio to see how everything goes. Also, I've intentionally broke the code in .sln file to see if the build step will fail and it didn't. Which means, that my script isn't getting a results from mdtool call. How do I fix it?

Thank you.